# Trying to access key in Nested Array of dictionaries in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

Perhaps I didn't phrase the question correctly but I need access to keys in an Array of dictionaries that are nested inside of another array of dictionaries. The closest I think I have gotten is

```
name: dict["name"] as! String,
speciesId: dict["species_id"] as! Int,
identifier: dict["identifier"] as! String,
typeId: dict["forms"]!["item0"]!["type_id"] as! Int
```

I can grab the first 3 variables but cannot grab the last one as it is nested inside another array of dictionaries. if someone could point me in the right direction for grabbing **type_id**. And When I tried

```
typeId: dict["type_id"] as! Int
```

It just returns as nil on the console.

UPDATE: So going off of one of answers here, using this line to gab an int from an array works

```
 formId: (dict["egg_groups"] as! Array<Int>)[0] as Int!
```

but when trying to grab a dict from the array I get EXC_BAD INSTRUCTION

Comment: Could you please share your Response? or JSON or XML string

Comment: It seems "forms" is an array, pass index in integer format instead of "item0" string.

Comment: @DheerajD I can view the source code but I have no software on my computer that lets me edit/ copy it. Essentially "forms" is an array with "item" as its dictionary and "type_id" as the key I need to grab

Comment: @bunty I'm sorry could you elaborate? I don't know what you mean

Comment: Just answer it below could you please try using that?

Comment: @user4938361 if forms is an array, so try using integer index to access element. First grab the array in "forms" variable and then try accessing using "forms[0]"

Comment: Are you trying you parse some server response ? if yes then share your json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this  and pass correct index as here is 0:

```
let typeId = (dict["forms"] as! Array<Dictionary<String,Any>>)[0]["type_id"]! as Int
```

Comment: I keep running into the EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION with no console error. I take it it might be returning nil?

Comment: Finally Got the code to work by changing `<String,Int>` to `<String,Any>`. Change your comment to reflect this and I'll mark your answer as accepted. Thank you!!